# Search URL parameters with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-parameters

Say I have a URL like this:

```
www.mysite.com?account=23&token=asdu756sdg65sdf
```

Now, I need to access those URL parameters individually using [Angular JS](https://angularjs.org/).

I've tried using `location.search` inside my controller:

```
console.log(location.search);
```

Which nicely returns the full query string:

```
?account=23&token=asdu756sdg65sdf
```

But it seems to return a string, not an object. Is there an easy way to access the individual ids and values in the string?

I've also tried:

```
console.log($location.search());
```

Which seems to return an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
var account = ($location.search()).account;
```

but the url should be like /#!/?account=1

Comment: Perfect thanks! I didn't realise I had to structure the URL differently, but it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

have your tried using it as a function instead?

`$location.search();`

Comment: Yes, that seems to return an empty object

Comment: $location on it's own seems to work. Any idea why the search function would be returning empty?

Comment: can you provide a plunker or a jsfiddle? It might be easier for us to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pure js way:

```
var getParamFromURL = function(_url) {
    var url = _url;
    var _paraString = url.indexOf("&") > -1 ? url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1, url.length).split("&") : url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1, url.length).split('');
    var _paraObj = {};
    for (i = 0; p = _paraString[i]; i++) {
        _paraObj[p.substring(0, p.indexOf("=")).toLowerCase()] = p.substring(p.indexOf("=") + 1, p.length);
    }
    return _paraObj;
}
```

via angular js:

```
 // Given:
 // URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
 // Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
 //
 // Then
 $routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

Great. @Cooper is right.

Comment: That looks like pure javascript to me. I'm pretty sure Angular JS has built in functions to do this job, and seeing as that's the framework I'm using for this project, I'd like to do it in that.

Comment: @Cooper no angular doesn't simply because angular routing is all after the hash and has no interest in `location.search`