# Multiple query string parameters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm struggling with passing and reading multiple query string parameters in a route.

```
$routeProvider.when("/joboffers:keywords:location", {
    controller: "jobOffersController",
    templateUrl: "/App/Views/JobOffer/All.html"
});
```

This is the search page:

```
$scope.searchJobOffer = function () {
    var vm = $scope.jobOfferSearchViewModel;
    var path = "/joboffers?keywords=" +( vm.keywords || "") + "&location=" + (vm.location || "");
    $location.path(path);
}
```

And this is the JobOffersController:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('jobOffersController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'jobOfferService', function ($scope, $routeParams, jobOfferService) {
    $scope.jobOffers = [];

    function init() {
        var keywords = $routeParams.keywords;
        var location = $routeParams.location;
    }

    init();
}]);
```

Reading the $routeParams is not working at all. If I pass "developer" as a keyword and "New York" as location, the $routeParam object looks like this:

```
{keywords: "?keywords=developer&location=New Yor", location: "k"}
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

P.S.
Is it possible that this is because of a wrongly configured route?
When I navigate via the `searchJobOffer` function, it encodes the URL to this: `http://localhost:49380/#/joboffers%3Fkeywords=developer&location=london` and if I try to use this url `http://localhost:49380/#/joboffers?keywords=developer&location=london`, the routing system drops me to the default route (#/home)

Comment: Please post the code of the JobOffersController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24981775/356380

Comment: $location.search() returns an empty object.

Comment: `$routeParams` are only updated after a route change completes successfully. You sure this is the case?

Comment: Since the controller is loaded, I'm pretty sure. But just to test it, I've moved the init() to a setTimeout() with 5 secs, and the $routeParams has the same value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$routeProvider does not match on query strings, only routes. Also, you're setting a full `url` to $location.path() and $location.path() only takes the `path` piece of the url. To set the entire URL including query string you need to use `$location.url()`.

Here are a few options:

#### 1. Use pretty URLs instead

```
$routeProvider.when("/joboffers/:location/:keywords", {
  controller: "jobOffersController",
  templateUrl: "/App/Views/JobOffer/All.html"
});

$scope.searchJobOffer = function () {
  var vm = $scope.jobOfferSearchViewModel;
  var path = "/joboffers/" + (vm.location || "") + "/" + ( vm.keywords || "");
  $location.path(path);
};

app.controller('jobOffersController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'jobOfferService', function ($scope, $routeParams, jobOfferService) {
  $scope.jobOffers = [];

  function init() {
    var keywords = $routeParams.keywords;
    var location = $routeParams.location;
  }

  init();
}]);
```

#### 2. Only match on the job offers path and pull the params from $location.search()

(note the use of `$location.url()` instead of `$location.path()`)

```
$routeProvider.when("/joboffers", {
  controller: "jobOffersController",
  templateUrl: "/App/Views/JobOffer/All.html"
});

$scope.searchJobOffer = function () {
  var vm = $scope.jobOfferSearchViewModel;
  var url = "/joboffers?keywords=" +( vm.keywords || "") + "&location=" + (vm.location || "");
  $location.url(url);
};

app.controller('jobOffersController', ['$scope', '$location', 'jobOfferService', function ($scope, $location, jobOfferService) {
  $scope.jobOffers = [];

  function init() {
    var search = $location.search();
    var keywords = search.keywords;
    var location = search.location;
  }

  init();
}]);
```

#### 3. If you need to match the route AND the query string, try something more robust like [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
$stateProvider.state("JobOffers", {
  url: '/joboffers?keywords&location',
  controller: "jobOffersController",
  templateUrl: "/App/Views/JobOffer/All.html"
});

$scope.searchJobOffer = function () {
  var vm = $scope.jobOfferSearchViewModel;
  var url = "/joboffers?keywords=" +( vm.keywords || "") + "&location=" + (vm.location || "");
  $location.url(url);
};

app.controller('jobOffersController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'jobOfferService', function ($scope, $stateParams, jobOfferService) {
  $scope.jobOffers = [];

  function init() {
    var keywords = $stateParams.keywords;
    var location = $stateParams.location;
  }

  init();
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer, I think I'll go with the second option.