# AngularJS router handling of infinite params in URL

Tags: angularjs, regex

Hi I'm working on my first AngularJS project. Here is my current route looks like,

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('report', {
      url: '/report/:Id',
      templateUrl: 'templates/report.html'
    })
```

The problem here is `/report/:reportId` is handling only the first level, whereas my URL is looking like, `/report/:val1/:val2/:val3/:val4/...` and so on. But it is only matching when the URL like `/report/:val1` and not anything after.

How to have my URL to match any level? Please help.

Comment: Please refer this answer.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692747/multiple-query-string-parameters-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself, when I use it with * before the params it is getting values matching up to any level but as a single parameter. Like if you have something like "/report/3/0", controller's `$stateParams` have `3/0`. So we can handle further from there.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('report', {
      url: '/report/*Id',
      templateUrl: 'templates/report.html'
    });

angular.module('app.controllers', [])
.controller('reportCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
      console.log($stateParams);
});
```

The above code will print "3/0" in console.