# Handle Query string in routeprovider or any other solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to handle query string like (index.php?comment=hello) in routeprovider while configuration in angularjs.

Example:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
    .when('/index.php?comment=hello',{
        redirectTo:'/index.php'
    });
```

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692747/multiple-query-string-parameters-in-angularjs

Comment: How i handle query string in route provider.

Comment: What do you want to do in `routeProvider`? You should handle query string in controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Your URL will look like:

```
http://www.heycodetech.com/#/viewPage/param1/param2
```

Here is your router file have the code:

```
$stateProvider.state('/viewPage/:param1/:param2', {
   templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',
   controller: 'MyCtrl'
});
```

And here is the code of controller for which you can get this value.

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$stateParams, $state) {
var param1 = $state.param1;
var param1 = $state.param2;
}]);
```

For more look [here](http://heycodetech.com/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angularjs/).

Comment: its not a solution of my question bro.

Comment: how i use this for routeProvider.

Comment: @ZubairSheikh Look here: http://heycodetech.com/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angularjs/

Comment: #PritamBanerjee i want to use index.php?comment=page in .when but the link for solution you provided me not working on my requirement.

Comment: @ZubairSheikh Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs

Comment: would you understand my problem?

Comment: my problem is I want to route the url in configuration.

Comment: @ZubairSheikh You cannot handle that in the configuration. You will have to do that in the controller.